# Position: Fixed isn't fixed?

Tags: html, css, facebook-like, position, fixed

I am trying to have my facebook like button stay in the top left corner and as the user scrolls down it follows them... What is wrong with my code? It shows but as I scroll down it does not move with the scroll. Tested locally on both of the latest versions safari and firefox. Please help!

```
 topleft{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }

<top> FACEBOOK "LIKE BUTTON" IFRAME CODE HERE </top>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't selecting your like button properly. You need to add a class attribute for css selection.

Try something like

```
<div class="facebook">FACEBOOK IFRAME</div>
```

Notice the ".facebook" rather than just "facebook".

```
.facebook {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured to make a div right after this.. I'm so new to coding =X I have it currently at...

`}
#topleft{
position: fixed;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 160px;
}`

but when I make my browser window smaller horizontally it scrolls over the main content of the page. how do i lock it horizontally but allow a vertical "fixed" position?

Comment: You can accomplish this by adding the facebook iframe to main content of the page. Then you need to fix only the top:0 and give the margin-left property the value of the facebook iframe width + the main content width.  Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/3EyXE/2/

Answer (score 1):

There's no `top` tag in HTML.

CSS class name selectors should be preceded by a `.` (period).

```
 topleft{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
```

should be

```
.topleft{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
```

Assigning the style you've created to the iframe should work.

```
 <iframe class="topleft" ...>
    ...
 </iframe>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkhmt/)

Answer (score 1):

problem with this could be

for topleft class

```
.topleft{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

for topleft id

```
#topleft{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

otherwise it should work.